# Is it possible to define a square root if the power series has leading term even power?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

We know that we can add and multiply two power series and we know that if a power series is nonzero at a point we can divide by it. Can we take a square root of a power series?

Let $f$ be holomorphic in a neighborhod around $z_0$ with the power series expansion $a_{2k}\ne0$

$$f(z)=\sum_{\substack{n=2k\\k\geq0}}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n.$$

Can we define a function $g$ such that $g^2=f$ in a neighborhood of $z_0$?

Comment: Your hypothesis give that you can _pre_ -compose with square root, not _post_ -compose... But/and see @RobertIsrael's answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the restriction to even powers.  Any function $f(z)$ analytic in a neighbourhood of $z_0$ such that $f(z_0) \ne 0$ has analytic square roots $\pm g(z)$ in a neighbourhood of $z_0$. This is because $\sqrt{z}$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $f(z_0)$ and the composition of analytic functions is analytic.

Comment: I guess OP is somehow aware of the issue that $\sqrt{f}$ may not be well-defined if $f(z_0) = 0$. Probably a more general condition is that there exists a non-negative integer $k$ such that $f^{(2k)}(z_0) \neq 0$ and $f^{(j)}(z_0) = 0$ for $0 \leq j < 2k$. Also, (+1)

Comment: With the given conditions of the OP, even if $f(z_0)=0$, we can still take the square root because we can extract $(z-z_0)^{2k}$